# W3 Total Cache plugin doesn't work without setting 777 permission for w3tc-config directory

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I have my Wordpress website running on Apache and installed **w3-total cache plugin** installed. To enable Page Cache, it wants me to set 777 permission to w3tc-config and cache folder.

It shows the following warning.

```
Execute next commands in a shell:
chmod 777 {MyDirectory}/wp-content/cache
chmod 777 {MyDirectory}/wp-content/w3tc-config
```

Is it secure? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using W3C Total Cache you should do :

```
chmod 777 wp-content/w3tc-config
chmod 777 wp-content/cache

rm -rf wp-content/cache/config
rm -rf wp-content/cache/object
rm -rf wp-content/cache/db
rm -rf wp-content/cache/minify
rm -rf wp-content/cache/page_enhanced
```

In this case,Everytime when you clear cache then w3tc  needs to regenerate a cache,So need write permission.

Comment: Its fine for me to leave cache folder writeable. I am not particularly comfortable with leaving w3tc-config folder writeable. Is there a way to make it work by changing the owner of those directories instead of giving 777 access.